# Array of doubles in java: How to create an array without mentioning the size and give it to another method for populating it

Tags: java, arrays

This may seem to be a very silly problem for many of you. But I have put in lots of time trying to figure it out.

I have a class which calls an API method. This method takes in an array of doubles as an argument. I don't know the size of this array beforehand and returns null. So the method updates the double array inside it. So, what can I do?

1. If I just create the array as below, it will be Null.

   ```
   double scores[];
   ```
2. If I use ArrayList(Double) and later try to convert to array using toArray(), I am getting errors.

   ```
   ArrayList<Double> scores=new ArrayList<Double>();

   obj.getScores(scores.toArray()); //Gives me compilation error because scores.toArray() gives Object Array, and we need double array.
   ```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You will need to manually copy the entries from the `ArrayList` to the `double` array...fun stuff...

Comment: What "errors" ? Specify your problem more thoroughly.

Comment: Can you have the method **return** the array instead?

Comment: `double scores[] = new double[ parameterArray.length ]`. `ArrayList<Double>` will not work because it stores `Double` objects instead of `double` values, so the resulting array is `Double[]` and cannot be assigned to a `double[]`.

Comment: "im getting errors" is too wide saying

Comment: Don't work with arrays, it's an opening for errors from your side. Use ArrayList or something similar.

Comment: do it this way `obj.getScores(scores.toArray(new Double[scores.size()]));`

Comment: @SparkOn That won't work, you won't be able to pass a Double[] to a method that expects a double[]. Autoboxing does not work that way around because of the possibility of null object references. What value would you expect the double representation of a null Double object to have?

Comment: If I understand it correctly you have to pass a void array to that method to get the array filled, right? Otherwise `.getScores(scores.toArray())` would semantically make no sense. If this is the case it is the method that should be rethinked.

Comment: Well, it sounds like an API implementation problem. Can you post the `getScores` code?

Comment: @Narmer It is not with me! I have communicated this to the development team for a change in the API.

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? A getter method with a parameter ringed a huge bell for me. You should make them re-re-write the implementation. Is them who should create the array for you because only them know the size of it. You have NO WAY to do it from your side.

Comment: Whoops, I read your comment wrong. I tought you asked them to change the API for the method to receive a parameter, sorry (_It is NOT with me_. I missed that _not_ somehow). My previous comment still makes sense tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java is pass-by-value, you can not directly pass the `double[]` array to have it **created** inside the method so that it is still visible when the method returns.

The closest solution you can get is to use a **container object**:

```
class DoubleContainer {
   public double[] theArray;
}

public class SampleContainer {

   public void populate(DoubleContainer dc) {
      dc.theArray = new double[2];
      dc.theArray[0] = 42.0;
      dc.theArray[1] = 43.0;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SampleContainer sc = new SampleContainer();

      // create the double[] container and call the API method
      DoubleContainer dc = new DoubleContainer();
      sc.populate(dc);

      System.err.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(dc.theArray));
   }
}
```

A much simpler alternative would be to return the array:

```
public class Sample {

   public double[] populate() {
      double[] result = new double[2];
      result[0] = 42.0;
      result[1] = 43.0;
      return result;
   }
}
```

On a side note, as others mentioned, consider using `ArrayList` instead of raw arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create an array without mentioning the size. Arrays are fixed-size, so this is not possible.

What you can do, however, is use a [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), e.g.

```
// variable size
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(...); // add your elements like that
```

Note the big 'D' in the double generic in the example code. This is a wrapper class for a normal double primitive.

if you need an array for reading the data, you can do:

```
double data[] = new double[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It would make more sense to redesign the API. Have the second method create its own array and return it to you.